# How to get circle coordinates in pymunk

Tags: pymunk

I'm using pymunk and I want to call the coordinates of a circle but it seems to be impossible for me.

For poly objects it's `ps = logo_shape.get_vertices()` but when the `logo_shape` refers to a circle object, I get this error from python :

```
  File "D:/package/essai_optimisé(test).py", line 233, in main
    ps = logo_shape.get_vertices()
AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'get_vertices'
```

I just want to add an image at a dynamic ball and make the image rotate like the ball itself.

Thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Circles work a little different from polygons, what you can get it is the center of the circle, its radius and its angle. But that should be enough if you just want to display an image where the circle is.

Basically

```
center = circle.body.position + circle.offset.rotated(circle.body.angle)
radius = circle.radius # scale image to match this
```

Take a look at draw_circle in pygame_util.py that is included with pymunk: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/pymunk/pygame_util.py